# Google Stackdriver does not show trace

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

Previously when an error occurred in my application I could find a trace of the entire code to where it happened ( file, line number ). In the Google Cloud console.

Right now I only receive a request ID and a timestamp, with no indication of a trace or line number in the code when in the 'logging' window in the Google Cloud Console. Selecting a 'log event' only shows some sort of JSON structure of a request, but not anything about the code or any helpful information what went wrong with the application.

What option should be selected in the google cloud console to show a stack trace for Python App Engine applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has in the mean time update the cloud console and debugger, which now does contain full stack traces for Python.